# The meaning of 'subclasses of the containing class' in Java?

Tags: java, class

I came across the expression  'subclasses of the containing class' when I read [a paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2393661). What does that `containing class` mean in Java? This is the excerpt from the paper.

`Primarily, this entailed three things: (i) studying the implementation of the entity, as well as its usage, to reason about the intent behind the functionality; (ii) performing static dependency analysis on the entity, and any other types, methods, or fields referenced by it, including constants; and (iii) examining the inheritance hierarchy and subclasses of the containing class. This approach took considerable time and effort to apply.`

Comment: Subclass of the containing class of _which_ element? The context should clarify the element.

Comment: It would help if you posted more context of the original quote. "Containing" is a fairly broad term.

Comment: Could you please post the part that you read in that paper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example has a subclass of the containing class:

```
class Parent {
    class Child {
    }
}

class ParentSubclass extends Parent {
    void whatever() {
        new Child(); // Creates an instance of Parent.Child
    }
}
```

`ParentSubclass` is a *subclass* of the *containing* class of `Child`. Note that *outside* of `Parent` (or its subclasses), `new Child()` will not work, as you *need* to have a containing ("outer") class to instantiate a non-`static` "inner" class.

Things get a bit crazy when you now add a method `doSomething` to `Parent`, invoke it in `Child` but override it in `ParentSubclass`.

```
class Parent {
    void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Not doing anything");
    }

    class Child {
        void whatever() {
            doSomething(); // actually: Parent.this.doSomething()
        }
    }
}

class ParentSubclass extends Parent {
    void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("I'm just slacking.");
    }

    void whatever() {
        Child a = new Child(); // Creates an instance of Parent.Child
        a.whatever(); // will print "I'm just slacking".
    }
}
```

Situations like this make static code analysis a quite hard problem.

Answer (score 2):

Since I have no access to the paper, this is my best guess: in Java, classes can be related to each other in more than one way: in addition to inheriting from one another, classes can also be *nested* inside one another.

Here is an example of a class inheriting from the class inside which it is nested:

```
public class Outer {
    public void doSomething() {
        // ...does something
    }
    private static class Inner extends Outer {
        public void doSomething() {
            // ...does something else
        }
    }
}
```

In the example above, `Inner` inherits from `Outer`, which serves as its containing class.

Comment: `static` inner classes are not truly *nested*. They might just as well just be in the same package for all practical purposes. And why is the `extends Outer` needed?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Well, nested `static` classes do gain access to elements of their outer classes that are declared `private`, as opposed to package-private elements accessible to other top-level classes sharing the same package. The `extends Outer` is there to make a class that is both nested and inheriting at the same time.